# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JokeEntityRepository (?)

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I am learning NestJS and I am trying to test a service which incorporates a repository with TypeORM. It compiles fine without errors, but when I run the test it throw an error.

I know it is a test dependency problem but I can't figure it out. I am trying this test:

```js
describe('JokesService', () => {
  let service: JokesService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [],
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([JokeEntity])
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<JokesService>(JokesService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The module:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [JokesService],
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([JokeEntity])
  ],
  controllers: [JokesController],
})
export class JokesModule {}
```

The service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class JokesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(JokeEntity)
    private readonly jokeRepository: MongoRepository<JokeEntity>
  ) {}
}
```

The main module:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      url: dbUri,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      ssl: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }),
    JokesModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And the error:

```sh
 Nest cant resolve dependencies of the JokeEntityRepository (?). 
Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If Connection is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
    - If Connection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing Connection */ ]
      })
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing in the test dependencies? Thank You.

Comment: What is it that you're testing here?

Comment: Nothing to be honest, just making sure the test which comes with the generate command works. I think it is just to test if the module works.

Comment: If you don't know what you're testing, you probably shouldn't be testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your `JokesModule` inside your `app.module`.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      url: dbUri,
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      ssl: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }),
    JokesModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It is already there, sorry, I missed that when copy/pasting

Comment: Ah okay, I can't help you more because I've never used typeOrm with MongoDB. When I use mongoDb with nestjs, I always use "Mongoose" as orm. If you want to check it, here is the nestjs doc: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#mongo and here is an official nestjs example: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/06-mongoose/src .